# Lock out TCP/IP Printer with username/password?

Tags: network-printer

Is there a method for ensuring people do not print to a TCP/IP based printer that shouldn't be? I am assuming that I only have control over a few computers, but the small group of us needs access to a printer. We do not want other users of the network to be able to print to this printer. Is there a configuration method that would block regular users from connecting to it without knowing some sort of parameter first?

I know that Mac OSX and Windows Vista/7/8 systems can automatically sniff out network printers when you ask it to. I would like to block this "feature" for this printer. How can I go about it with *Samsung* brand of printer?

Comment: Completely depends on the printer.  There is no generic method that can be configured across a wide variety of printers.  The most generic solution is to put it behind a firewall, and permit access only via a Print server that authenticates/authorizes usage of the printer.

Comment: @Zoredache Thanks. Updated question to not be as general

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its not an enterprise level printer with Active Directory/LDAP integration, a user can always map directly to the IP of the printer.  The best thing you can do is lock down network access, so that the printer can *only* communicate to the AD print server IP at the switch level.  By doing this, people can not directly connect to the printer and bypass the share restrictions on the print server.

Comment: I don't think that's possible in my network :-/ So I'm guessing it won't be possible. For reference for other visitors, can you expand the answer about the AD/LDAP integration?

Comment: There are multiple ways to accomplish locking down, such as firewall/switch rules, different subnets, etc.  None of these methods are doable for you?

Comment: also, you *could* share it off a computer with a different NIC on a PC.  That way its NATed behind the PC...

Comment: I have a Windows 2000 AD server, but I don't know how that would go about it... But, the switch is a simple D-Link Home-based router that has very, very, VERY basic features on it... No L2 or L3 routing is possible on it

Comment: As for AD/LDAP aware printers, they have the functionality to lock down access to the printers and limit themselves to the share permissions set in AD/LDAP.  They will not take direct connections via IP.  Also, access can be manually given at the printer level, which can traverse AD/LDAP.  This method is a pain to set up usually.

Comment: can it be done with DD-WRT?  I personally dont know, as I have never used it.  However, a cheap router and a flash might solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Most networked printers allow you to create an "access list". This is a list of IP addresses for the PCs that are allowed to use the printer. If the list is empty, everybody has access. You can use the list in 2 ways.

1. If only a small number of users need access, put their IP addresses in the list. You may need to make sure the PCs have static addresses.
2. Put just the Ip address of the server in the list. Then set the permissions on the server itself.

If your printer supports it, the access list should be accessible from the printer's web page.